# how to assign for loop index to bit field

Tags: c, bit-fields

How to design a code to pass the bit location.

```
typedef struct
{
  A   :1;
  B   :1;
  C   :1;
  D   :1;
}bit;

void main()
{
  bit Bit_Pass = 0;
  uint8 a = 0;
  for (a = 0; a<4; a++)
  {
    Bit_Pass.[a] = TRUE /*the code is not correct in this line. the goal is to set the bit of a in Bit_Pass*/
  }
}
```

The goal is to set the bit of a in Bit_Pass

Comment: You cannot do this. The only data object you can access via an index is an array. Bitfields are not arrays. You might try with a union that overlays your bitfield with an integer value and access the bits in that integer via bitmasks.

Comment: You want to set the most significant bit or the least significant bit? Which one do you think `Bit_Pass.A = 1` would set and why? Bottom line, you can't take an address of bitfield member. Just use `|=` binary operations.

Comment: There are several syntax errors here: 1) TRUE should be true.  2) A semicolon is missing. 3)  Bit_Pass should be initialized using curly braces since it is a struct (i.e bit Bit_Pass = {0};). 4) There should be no brackets around a in Bit_Pass.[a].  You should address bitfield members the same way you address members of any struct.